# Can't print last digit of a number while displaying all digits of a number using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I was trying to print digits of a number using recursion. The function I defined returns all the digits but I fail to print the last digit. Can any one point out what's wrong in the code? Is there any other logic which is better than this with recursion?

```
 public static int printIndividualDigits(int num){
        if((num/10) != 0){
           System.out.print(printIndividualDigits(num/10)+ ",");
        }
         if(num != 0){
           return num%10;
        }else{
             return 0;
         }
    }
```

Comment: The code works ... I think a downvote is too harsh... I was just curious if I can improve the code. Please enlighten me regarding the downvote....

Comment: When I run your code I'm getting the output `4,3,5,6,7,9` which isn't missing any last digit. What exactly makes you think a digit is missing in your output?

Comment: If your code works and there is no error, you should know that your question isn't a good fit for stackoverflow and would rather belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Bro, please run the code in main method without using println() statement... You are confused because my main method.. waait let me edit it...

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS call the printIndividualDigits(int num) method without using sout statement....

Comment: If you run the code with a debugger step by step, it should be straightforward to see why your code does not work, and find how to fix it.

Comment: Here's a little hint: your method is named `"printIndividualDigits"`. Does it really need to return an `int`?

Comment: @MA You are right.... your hint worked....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you *return* the last character, but you *print* all the others.

In your recursive calls, you don't append the reminder to some globally available variable (which would be preferable way in your example), hence you don't *build* the answer to be printed; rather you just print the remainders, per each recursive call, and then (important) *return* either `num%10` or `0`.

So, your first stack frame (which is initial method call, first entrance into the recursive method) **returns**, instead of printing.

For instance, if you will take number `3435`, your last recursive call ends up to be:

```
System.out.print(printIndividualDigits(34/10)+ ",");
```

which enters `printIndividualDigits` with argument 3 passed into "num" parameter, and then method prints `3%10` => `3`.

Now, when your recursive calls pop off the stack frame - that is your recursion goes back to the first recursive frame (that is a first recursive call), variable `num` is 3435, **there is no more recursive calls*, and code execution passes `System.out#print` method call, to the `if` checks, after which, it **returns** either `0`, or the latest reminder, instead of printing it.

So, in the first stack frame, your `return 3435%10`, which is `5`, gets just returned and not printed.

Answer (score -2):

change int to double try it

```
`
 public static double printIndividualDigits(double num){
        if((num/10) != 0){
           System.out.print(printIndividualDigits(num/10)+ ",");
        }
         if(num != 0){
           return num%10;
        }else{
             return 0;
         }
    }

`
```